# Entity-Relationship diagram with join to either of two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, entity-relationship

I have three entities - 'Device', 'Module', and 'Port', and wish to find the correct way in which they should be designed in an Entity-Relationship.

A **Device** has many **Modules**.

A **Module** has many **Ports**.

A **Device** has many **Ports**.

I have designed the following Entity Relationships, which I am looking for confirmation on if they are correct.

**Device**

- DeviceID

**Module**

- ModuleID

**Port**

- PortID
- DeviceID
- ModuleID

However, I am confused how a join could be made between the port table and the device or module tables if the port could be on either of the two. For example, if I knew the port and wanted to find out information about its parent. My question is, is this E-R diagram correct? And how would I be able to join a port with the other table to get information about its parent, if it could belong to either a device or a module?

Many thanks in advance for any help or comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setup will work fine.  The `Port` table will have either a `DeviceID` or a `ModuleID`.  The other will be **null**.

A query to get all the information may look something like the following:

```
SELECT d.*, m.*, p1.PortID as ModulePort, p2.PortID as DevicePort, 
FROM Device d
INNER JOIN Module m On d.ModuleID = m.ModuleID
INNER JOIN Ports p1 on p1.ModuleID = m.ModuleID
INNER JOIN Ports p2 on p2.DeviceID = m.DeviceID
```

Your other option could be to change the `Port` table to the following:

**Port**

- PortID
- ObjectID
- Type

and use a query similar to:

```
SELECT d.*, m.*, p1.PortID as ModulePort, p2.PortID as DevicePort, 
FROM Device d
INNER JOIN Module m On d.ModuleID = m.ModuleID
INNER JOIN Ports p1 on p1.ObjectID = m.ModuleID AND Type = 'Module'
INNER JOIN Ports p2 on p2.ObjectID = m.DeviceID AND Type = 'Device'
```

In either case you can see to get the `Port` information for both `Device` and `Module`, you link to the table twice.